# How to use fromInteger in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

One way to calculate 2^8 in haskell is by writing

```
product(replicate 8 2)
```

When trying to create a function for this, defined as follows...

```
power1 :: Integer →  Integer → Integer
power1 n k | k < 0 = error errorText
power1 n 0 = 1
power1 n k = product(replicate k n)
```

i get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type 'Int' against inferred type 'Integer'
```

My guess is that I must use the fromInteger function somewhere... I'm just not sure where or how? Is it an interface or what is fromInteger, and how should I use it?

Thanks

Comment: It's worth noting that `product [] = 1`, so you don't actually need your special case for `k = 0` (because `replicate 0 x = []`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, never use fromInteger. Use fromIntegral.

You can see where the type error is by looking at the type of replicate:

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

so when you giv it 'k' as an argument, which you've asserted is an Integer via the type declaration, we have a type error.

A better approach for this would be to use genericReplicate:

```
genericReplicate :: (Integral i) => i -> a -> [a]
```

So then:

```
power1 n k = product (genericReplicate k n)
```

Comment: you should mention that `genericReplicate` is in `Data.List` module

Comment: @Mickel There is no need for the function seeing as `forall (Integral x, Eq x) => x. fromInteger x == fromIntegral x`

Comment: Can you backup `Firstly, never use fromInteger`? Why?

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the rest of the error message as well, it tells you exactly the answer to your question:

```
Couldnt match expected type 'Int' against inferred type 'Integer'
In the first argument of 'replicate', namely 'k'
In the first argument of 'product', namely '(replicate k n)'
In the expression: product (replicate k n)
```

"In the first argument of replicate". That's the place to add the `fromIntegral`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a simpler solution is to change the function's type definition to:

```
power1 :: Integer -> Int -> Integer
```